# How to check the url of a redirected domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

To clarify, I am not after the url of my server, or the scripts running on my server. What I have is a game program that I rent out to other sites who wish to use it for traffic building. The game runs on my server so I can take care of any administration or programming issues.  How I normally handle this is they create a folder with the same name as on my server, and use a .htaccess in that folder to redirect. The result is the game runs apparently from their site (the URI is their domain), but it actually is running on my server.

Now, one of my newer games, a customer wishes to have a 3 month exclusive right to run it from their site.  Since their site and my site are not on the same server, I cant use sessions to track if they visited the customers site first before accessing the game.

What I am wanting is to use php to check what the original URI was before redirecting. THat is.. the URI the end user sees in their browser.

Any assistance will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Not with PHP.  You would need Javascript to get information from the client side and send it back.

Comment: Considering it is using PHP why don't you provide an API key to the site?

Comment: How the game «run from» customer site? The game is embedded, or there are a link to your site? Or the call to your site is server-side?

Comment: You also could install kind of a proxy script which calls your server and returns the result in "passthru" mode. Of course. besides the usual parameters,  the proxy script could send additional information to your server

Answer (score 0):

You can use in PHP the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] which contain origin domain of the HTTP request.